# Gson parser class for dynamic json key value - Android

Tags: android, gson

I've used gson library for parsing json response. its working well. now i got a problem .

i've got below response from webservice. the json key value is not static, it will dynamically change.

how to write a parser class to parse the below response.

**Formatted JSON**:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 201,
        "dataPropertyName": "activity",
        "currentTime": "2014-02-05 06:15:04",
        "listedCount": "2"
    },
    "activity": [
        {
            "comments": [
                {
                    "raja": {
                        "type": "Liked",
                        "userPhoto": "663.png",
                        "userId": "74",
                        "userName": {
                            "1_0": "longjump"
                        },
                        "postOwner": "you",
                        "postDetails": {
                            "471": {
                                "postImage": "972.png",
                                "postId": "471",
                                "postType": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        "dateTime": "2014-02-05 05:24:56",
                        "sameOwner": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "follow": [
                {
                    "you": {
                        "type": "follow",
                        "followByUserName": {
                            "0_0": "olivepop",
                            "1_0": "yadidroy",
                            "2_0": "chitra"
                        },
                        "followUserName": "you",
                        "followByUserPhoto": "242.png",
                        "followUserPhoto": "953.png",
                        "dateTime": "2014-01-09 06:50:42"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "notifications": [
        "Activities has been retrieved successfully"
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you have a particular key which would be dynamic

Comment: which fields are not static...? All are same in the example json str that you provided.

Comment: in that response raja,471,you,1_0,2_0,3_0, are dynamic key value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this parser class

```
Meta meta = new Meta();

    ArrayList<Activity> activity = new ArrayList<ActivityParser.Activity>();

    ArrayList<String> notifications = new ArrayList<String>();

    public class Meta
    {
        String code,dataPropertyName,currentTime,listedCount;
    }

    public class Activity
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, CommentsItem>> comments = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,CommentsItem>>();

        public class CommentsItem
        {
            String type,userPhoto,userId,postOwner,dateTime,sameOwner;
            HashMap<String, String> userName = new HashMap<String,String>();
            HashMap<String, PostDetails> postDetails = new HashMap<String,PostDetails>();
            public class PostDetails
            {
                String postImage,postId,postType;
            }

        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, FollowItem>> follow = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,FollowItem>>();

        public class FollowItem
        {
            String type,followUserName,followByUserPhoto,followUserPhoto,dateTime;
            HashMap<String, String> followByUserName = new HashMap<String,String>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specification, you can make a Default Webservice response model.java which would be something like:

```
String success;
@SerializedName("error_msg")
String errorMessage;
@SerializedName("error_code")
String errorCode;
JsonObject data;
```

where the Parent of the object with dynamic keys would be the "data".
Use Gson, map the model class:

```
webserviceResponse= gson.fromJson(contentResponse,WebserviceResponse.class);
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(webserviceResponse.getSuccess()) && 
StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(webserviceResponse.getSuccess(), "success")) {
//check for the dynamic key name
                JsonObject job = webserviceResponse.getData();
                dynamicallyDefinedKeyClass= gson.fromJson(job.get("dynamicKeyValue"), DynamicallyDefinedKeyClass.class);
            }
```

Will edit my answer on question edit, in any way if it can help
Just a suggestion - raja, you etc. can be values for a key - name or commentsBy ? Where are you getting this response from?

Comment: how can i know "dynamicKeyValue". it will change every webservice. then how can i give the dynamicKeyvalue

Comment: inside "raja" ..the objects and keys aren't dynamic -"type","userPhoto","userId" ..so you need the model class for the content of "raja" , "you" -which you'l get from the Json Object

Answer (score 0):

If possible get a JSON response with all possible "Key" values and then get the POJO class auto build from below link:

[POJO FOR GSON](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

It will automatically handle all the posibilities. But make sure the RESPONCE you are providing while generating the POJO should hold all the possible combinations of your Key [changing once].

HOPE THIS HELPS!!

Comment: this can not be helpful in case of dynamic keys. because it will try to consider separate class for each object with different dynamic key though the contents are going to remain same